# How to access and modify alternate data streams (ADS) with go

Tags: go, filesystems, ntfs, alternate-data-stream

How can I access and modify metadata stored in NTFS alternate data streams with golang?

I already know about https://github.com/pkg/xattr for accessing metadata stored in extended attribures under linux. However, i need comparable functionality for NTFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate data streams can be accessed using ":StreamName" syntax when opening a file in NTFS.

```
ads, err := os.Open("C:\Path\To\My\File:MyHiddenStream")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```